# What is the Elm equivalent of Haskell's Show?

Tags: haskell, elm

I implemented my custom type in Elm:

`type Bin = BEmpty | One Bin | Zero Bin`

I want it to be showable when I use it in `String` context similar to:

```
main = 
  Html.p (text bin)
```

if, for example, following is defined:

```
bin : Bin
bin = One (One (Zero BEmpty))
```

If I try to define instance of `Show` as follows:

```
instance Show Bin
  show bin = show (binToDec bin)
```

I get following error:

```
-- NAMING ERROR --------------------------------------------------- src/Main.elm

I cannot find a `Bin` variant:

19| instance Show Bin 
                  ^^^
These names seem close though:

    EQ
    Err
    GT
    L
```

Is there an equivalent of Haskell's `instance Show Bin where` declaration in Elm?

Comment: Elm unfortunately doesn't have type classes, or any equivalent (witness for example the many `map` functions in different modules), so you're pretty much out of luck here.

Comment: Why not define a specially named function, like `showBin`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Elm does not have this feature.  You need to implement your own `toString` function:

```
binToString : Bin -> String
binToString bin =
    binToDec bin
    |> String.fromInt
```